# piechart, dashboard, ControlWrapper, ComboChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

i have pie chart with the different slides :

```
   function drawChart(response) {
             if (response.isError()) {
             alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
             return;
        }   
             var data = response.getDataTable();
             var options = {'title':'XXXXXXXXXXX ........',
                           'width':900,
                           'height':300};
             var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
             chart.draw(data, options);
             // clickabale
             google.visualization.events.addListener(chart,'select', function(){;
                   var sel = chart.getSelection();
                   if(sel.length > 0) {
                       var building_name = data.getValue(sel[0].row, 0);
                       alert(building_name);
                       sendQueryBuildingName(building_name)            
       }
       });   
       }
```

and know i want that whene i click in on slides it send one query like this :

```
   function sendQueryCityName(cityName) {

          var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://api.XXXX.com/XXXX/datasource?table='+cityName);
          query.setQuery('select cost_reportings_timestamp, sum (cost_reportings_cost) group by cost_reportings_timestamp pivot ecoadmin_zone_name where(ecoadmin_building_name = 'building_name')');             
          query.send(drawChart);
        console.log(response);
        }
```

on my database and after it send the data to my bar chart ....

could you help me ????

Comment: Which part is causing problems for you?

Comment: @asgallant i don't know how i can say in my code that when i click in on of the slides of my piechart it show my the combochart that is related with it, you know every slides of my piechart it present on bulding and when i click in it, it show my the different zon (with combochart) that exist in my building....

Answer (score 1):

Without having more specific information, I can't give you a full solution, but here's some code that should get you started:

```
function drawChart(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }   
    var data = response.getDataTable();
    var options = {
        'title':'XXXXXXXXXXX ........',
        'width':900,
        'height':300
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    // clickabale
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart,'select', function(){
        var sel = chart.getSelection();
        if(sel.length > 0) {
            var building_name = data.getValue(sel[0].row, 0);
            alert(building_name);
            sendQueryBuildingName(building_name)            
        }
    });   
}
function sendQueryBuildingName(buildingName) {

    var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://api.XXXX.com/XXXX/datasource?table='+buildingName);
    query.setQuery('select cost_reportings_timestamp, sum (cost_reportings_cost) group by cost_reportings_timestamp pivot ecoadmin_zone_name where(ecoadmin_building_name = ' + buildingName + ')');             
    query.send(drawComboChart);
}
function drawComboChart (response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }   
    var data = response.getDataTable();
    var options = {
        'title':'XXXXXXXXXXX ........',
        'width':900,
        'height':300
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('combo_chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```